# Spilled Milk on MacBook Air, wondering what could be the issue with it and what I could do to fix it

Tags: memory, ssd, motherboard, macbook-air

I spilled milk on my MacBook Air about 2 months ago. I just took out the SSD and it works fine, though my macbook is still malfunctioning. (It doesn't start.). What potential issues do I have? I know that one issue could be my mobo... how could I fix that at a relatively inexpensive cost?

Thanks in advance for any answers. (MBA is mid 2011 13")

Comment: You will more than likely have to replace the whole laptop.

Comment: Milk wil get sour. Acid will eat away part of the motherboard. So 1) Do **not** try to start it.2) remove the battery and keep it unplugged.  3) Bring to to a place which can care for it or disassemble it and wash it was wash it with pure (distilled) water. Then let it dry completely. (Even if that takes days. Do not hurry this step.).

Answer (score 1):

If it is the motherboard you will most likely need to replace the entire computer. Sometimes spilled water won't adversely affect a laptop (if it is turned off you can wait for it to dry and it won't short-circuit), but liquid with sugar tends to cause corrosion. I would bring it in to a couple stores first to make sure you get a proper diagnosis.